# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) while iterating over a list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, unix

I have a list:

```
imageList = [(cloud/image_stored_docker:1.1.0, tarfile-1.1.0.tar),
             (cloud/image_stored_docker:1.2.0, tarfile-1.2.0.tar)]
```

I need to split in two lists, one list with keys (where images are keys) and other one with values (tarfiles).

I am trying to create a string and then convert it to list

```
for key, value  in imageList.items():
    images = images + key + ","

images = list(images)
```

but I get this message:

```
for key, value  in imageList.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I tried other way; removing `items()` function and this is the message:

```
for key, value  in imageList:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Removed fluff at end.\

Comment: I think drop the ".items()".   It's not a dictionary, it's a list of pairs.

Comment: Go through each tuple in the imageList and separate out the tuple into keys and values.

Comment: Are the items in `imageList` tuples of two *strings*? It's unclear from your question because what's shown is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to print a list of the keys you can use a list comprehension and iterate over the tuples

```py
imageList = [("cloud/image_stored_docker:1.1.0", "tarfile-1.1.0.tar"), ("cloud/image_stored_docker:1.2.0", "tarfile-1.2.0.tar") ]
keys = [pair[0] for pair in  imageList]
print(",".join(keys))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
cloud/image_stored_docker:1.1.0,cloud/image_stored_docker:1.2.0
```

Comment: Thank you, so much!!!